# Can a TCP/IP client connect to an unreachable IP?

Tags: c++, tcp

I've been searching for ages for my problem and I probably fell 20 times on stackoverflow without finding anything.

Here's my thing : I'm trying to develop a simple TCP/IP client in C++ (I've followed the well written Beej's Guide) that is supposed to communicate with a python TCP/IP server.

My code is (in a function) :

```
memset(&m_hints, 0, sizeof m_hints);
m_hints.ai_family=AF_UNSPEC;
m_hints.ai_socktype=SOCK_STREAM;
m_portnbrstring=to_string(m_portnbr);
if ((m_getaddrinfostatus=getaddrinfo(m_serverIP,(const char*) m_portnbrstring.c_str(), &m_hints, &m_servinfo))!=0)
{
    char tempstrerror[100];
    strcpy(tempstrerror,"getaddrinfo in TCPStartClient: ");
    strcat(tempstrerror,gai_strerror(m_getaddrinfostatus));
    ExitAndDisplayMessage(tempstrerror);
}
for(m_plist=m_servinfo; m_plist!=NULL; m_plist=m_plist->ai_next)
{
    if ((m_sockfd=socket(m_plist->ai_family, m_plist->ai_socktype, m_plist->ai_protocol))==-1)
    {
        perror("Something went wrong when creating TCP socket");
        continue;
    }
    break;
    if (connect(m_sockfd, m_plist->ai_addr, m_plist->ai_addrlen)==-1)
    {
        close(m_sockfd);
        perror("Something went wrong when connecting to TCP socket");
        continue;
    }
    break;
}
if (m_plist==NULL) ExitAndDisplayMessage("getaddrinfo in TCPStartClient: failed to connect");
char tempaddr[INET6_ADDRSTRLEN];
inet_ntop(m_plist->ai_family,get_in_addr((struct sockaddr *)m_plist->ai_addr),tempaddr, sizeof tempaddr);
cout << "TCPClient started at IP " << tempaddr << " on port " << ntohs(get_in_port((struct sockaddr *)m_plist->ai_addr)) << endl;
```

The definitions are

```
int m_sockfd;
char *m_serverIP;
struct addrinfo m_hints;
struct addrinfo *m_servinfo;
struct addrinfo *m_plist;
```

Until here, everything looks fine but the connect function keeps sending 0 (no error) even if the IP I specify is unreachable. Basically, connect() works even if the server is down or if a test with a random IP (I tested with fping to be unreachable).

Does anyone have an idea of what's happening ? I'd be glad if someone could kick me out of this.

Comment: Please [learn how to debug your program](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). If you do, then you will see that `connect` isn't even *called*.

Comment: damn, the break... I've been searching for ages...

Answer (score 0):

"Can a TCP/IP client connect to an unreachable IP?" - No. Obviously not.

If whatever you are using to establish a connection reports a successful connection of a TCP socket to an unreachable IP, then whatever you are using is broken (or you are using it wrong (probably the most likely situation) or the IP *is* in fact reachable).

Comment: Thanks for your fast answer ! That's what I thought... I tried to ping the address on which the connect is done and it's well unreachable. I don't understand what's happening.